# What is the default bean id using @Bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

if in a Java configuration class of a Spring application I have this bean definition:

```
 @Bean
 public MyBean myBean() {
     // instantiate and configure MyBean obj
     return obj;
 }
```

what is the bean is? Is it **MyBean**?

Comment: This is answered in the third sentence of [`@Bean`'s documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) - was asking a question less effort than looking it up?

Comment: The word "id" is not even present in the docs you linked. Please don't tell me they are the "same thing" without backing it up with a source of reference =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bean name is the same as the method name. In this case `myBean`.

Comment: Can we start off by defining what a bean id is? What makes a bean name the same as a bean id? I have not found a valid source on this.